# Editing /etc/fstab to permanently bind mount directory

Tags: centos, mount, lvm, fstab, bind-mount

I wish to make the following mount permanent:

```
[michael@devserver ~]$ findmnt | grep public
└─/home/jail/home/public/repo         /dev/mapper/centos-root[/home/michael/testing/gateway/repo] xfs        ro,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
[michael@devserver ~]$
```

I created this mount using the following:

```
sudo mkdir /home/jail/home/public/repo
sudo mount --bind /home/michael/testing/gateway/repo /home/jail/home/public/repo
sudo mount -o remount,ro,bind /home/jail/home/public/repo
```

My `/etc/fstab` currently looks like the following. 
 I expected that I should just add `/home/michael/testing/gateway/repo   /home/jail/home/public/repo   xfs   ro,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota   0   0` to `/etc/fstab`, but upon doing so, my server chokes and I have to go in emergency mode to remove this line from `/etc/fstab`.  What is the proper way to permanently bind mount a directory for read-only access?

```
[michael@devserver ~]$ cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Fri Apr  8 14:15:42 2016
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/centos-root /                       xfs     defaults        1 1
UUID=362355d4-e5da-44de-bf5c-5ce92cf43888 /boot                   xfs     defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/centos-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0

[michael@devserver ~]$
```

Comment: I can't see the `bind` option in your fstab's line... 
Take a look here: https://serverfault.com/a/613184

Comment: @setevoy  Thank you.  Shouldn't be blindly copying `findmnt` output when it comes to `/etc//fstab`!  You think options `bind,ro`?  Also, use `none` for the filesystem per your referenced link or `xfs` per `findmnt`s output?  Lastly, the tailing `0 0` not needed, right?

Comment: Your `/etc/fstab` entry should look like as follows. `/home/michael/testing/gateway/repo /home/jail/home/public/repo none bind,ro 0 0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, your `/etc/fstab` file does not seem to have `bind` mount-point configured.
Be so kind and add the following line:

`/home/michael/testing/gateway/repo /home/jail/home/public/repo none bind,ro 0 0.`

Then, I would type the following command to verify, if mountpount is persistent and works.

`mount /home/jail/home/public/repo`

After that, you can reboot your system.